# How to compare all fields in several rows in one table with result true or false (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, comparison

I have such table (for example):

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | c | c |  |
| 1 | a | x | c |  |
| 1 | a | c | c |  |
| 2 | a | y | j |  |
| 2 | b | y | k |  |
| 2 | b | y | l |  |

I need to select by one field by one value and compare all fields in selected rows, like SELECT * WHERE Filed1=1.....COMPARE

I would like to have a result like:

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | false | true |  |

Comment: What exactly do you want? Given a colum ```x``` and a value ```y```, you want all tuples ```t``` where ```t.x = y```, as I understand. And then you want to compare the values per column somehow, don't you? Can you clarify how to compare? I assume there is no corresponding output column for ```x```, but for all other columns?

Comment: I want to have as result only ONE row with TRUE and FALSE values. For example I compare 10 rows with the same value of the FIeld1 (Field1 it is Foreign Key)  and if all 10 rows of Field2 have the same value, I will have the result of Field2=TRUE, if for example Filed2 all 10 rows not the same the result should be FALSE; And the same algorithm with other all Fields

Answer (score 1):

This should work for fixed columns and if there are no `NULL` values:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.col1) = 1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.col2) = 1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.col3) = 1,
    ...
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.filter_column = 'some_value'
GROUP BY col1;
```

If you have some nullable columns, perhaps you could give it a try with something like this instead of the `COUNT(DISTINCT t.<colname>) = 1`:

```sql
    BOOL_AND(NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM mytable t2
        WHERE t2.filter_column = 'some_value'
            AND t2.<colname> IS DISTINCT FROM t.<colname>
    ))
```

If you do not have fixed columns, you should try to build up a dynamic query by a function taking as parameters the tablename, the name of the filter-column and the value for the filter.

Another remark: If you remove the filter (the condition `t.filter_column = 'some_value'`) and add another output column as just `t.filter_column`, you should be able to recieve the result of this query for all distinct values in your filter-column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is it possible not to write all columns like COUNT(DISTINCT t.col1) = 1..., but like “*”, because I need to compare all columns, but the are more than 500.

Comment: What Can I do to use your construction for array?

Comment: What do you mean with "for array"? In general the ```COUNT``` and the ```BOOL_AND(NOT EXISTS())``` variant should also support arrays. Do you have an example where it is not working?
Regarding an approach for many columns: have a look at PL/pgSQL and its ```EXECUTE``` for dynamic queries: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN
You could use this in combination with a lookup of the columns of the given table via ```pg_class``` and ```pg_attribute```

Comment: Hi, yes it works if array integer[] fully the same, but for example if I compare arrays integer[1,2,3] and integer[3,2,1] they are not the same, and I do not know how to use ORDER for array with DISTINCT and COUNT

Comment: Perhaps it might be useful to store your values ordered.
Otherwise, have a look at ```unnest()``` and then use ```array_agg()``` with an ```ORDER BY``` to make it a (sorted) array again. Then you can use the result of this subselect as your column.